# exec or shell_exec or timeout windows server 2016

Tags: php, exec, system, shell-exec, windows-server-2016

by now I try to use `shell_exec` or exce to print a file via FoxitReader.
But I think the server blocks this operation. In `php.ini` is nothing of that features blocked.

The command that I run is:

```
exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Foxit Software\\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe\" /t \"" . $Filename . " \" \"\\\\DRUCKER\\" . $toPrint["printOn"] . "\"");
```

I run that exactly command in command line, and that works. But via php Script this code did not run.

How can I solve this problem? On Windows client there is no problem with these functions...

Comment: can you run that command (under the same user account as your PHP application runs under) directly in the command prompt? And what _is_ the command exactly? If you don't show us, we're unlikely to know whether it could potentially cause problems. Also, is FoxitReader installed on the server? Does the server have access to the necessary printer? All this is relevant information we do not know about your environment, and which you haven't told us.

Comment: @ADyson: the command that I run is:  `exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Foxit Software\\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe\" /t \"" . $Filename . " \" \"\\\\DRUCKER\\" . $toPrint["printOn"]  . "\"");`

I run that exactly command in command line, and that works. But via php Script this code did not run

Comment: "I run that exactly command in command line"...really? I assume that in reality you substituted something else for the `" . $Filename . "` and `" . $toPrint["printOn"] . "` parts, rather than running _exactly_ the same command. I also assume you probably didn't do all the escaping of backslashes. So 1) have you been able to verify that the value of `$Filename` is what you expected, and the same as your hard-coded value in the command-line version? 2) Can you verify the same for `toPrint["printOn"]`? You could temporarily hard-code some values in the PHP version, to rule these variables out.

Comment: 3) Above you've randomly escaped some backslashes and not others. I'm not sure the escaping is necessary. once you've verified points 1 and 2, try it without the extra backslashes. if that doesn't work, try it with all the backslashes escaped (not just some of them). P.S. it would help if you showed us the version you successfully ran on the server's command-line, for comparison.

Comment: One small thing too: `$Filename . " \"` ...you've left a space after the end of the filename, but before the quote mark which is supposed to mark the end of the filename to the command-prompt. So that could potentially cause confusion too.

Comment: @ADyson, you are correct. the variables are filled with: `$Filename` = Fullpath to pdf and `$toPrint["printOn"]`is networkprinter path. The error in `$Filename` I fixed - it does not matter the FoxitReader. But still on windows server there is no `exec` handling. My thought is, that the loggedin Windowsuser (Domainuser) has no rights to start `cmd.exe` from `system32`. I checked this, but I can not changed the user even I'm doamainadmin....